# Macro condition to hide zone on the basis of document role

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, kentico

I am using a webpart-zone with two web parts in Kentico v7:

1. Editable text
2. Repeater

In the repeater I am using relationships to display data according to user's role and permissions assigned to it. It is working. I have put the condition in the webpart as:

```
{%CurrentDocument.RelatedDocuments.isrelatedto.Count>0#%}
```

I want to hide the complete zone, entire block, if there is no data. But the problem is that for some roles, the condition `{%CurrentDocument.RelatedDocuments.isrelatedto.Count>0#%}` returns `true` because it contain data but this should not be visible to the user as per his / her role permissions. In such a case it shows a blank web part. I don’t want to show this blank web part, I want to hide this completely.

What condition I should add for this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite specific need. I'd recommend creating your own macro method. There are detailed [instructions in developer's guide](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/registering_cutom_macro_methods.htm) regarding registration of such method. Your method would take the permissions into account and return true or false based on them.